Does there exist a constant factor approximate solution for capacitated vehicle routing problem?
I know that there is a 1.5 approximate solution for metric traveling salesman problem (TSP), e.g., Christofedes algorithm guarantees this. Is there an algorithm that guarantees a constant factor approximate solution for CVRP as well?
I searched papers but could not find anything except for some very special cases where constant factor is achieved, but not for general metric CVRP.

Maybe this link would be useful.
